# MVVM WPF bindings with RelativeSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestModel}">    
    <Button Content="Button" " Margin="0">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <mvvm:EventToCommand  
                    Command="{Binding ImageClick, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True"/>
             </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Hi all,

Above I have a data template which is switching on certain data type using a data template. I am using the mvvm pattern. I want to be to bind to the ImageClick property.

I was able to do this before, but since I have moved the button inside the data template I am unable to bind to that property.

I think I need to use Relative source for the binding but am really unsure how to do it.

Help on this would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596094/bind-command-from-business-object-to-view-in-mvvm/10596243#10596243

Comment: It looks ok, depending on where the ImageClick command is.  Can we see the view model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding to viewmodel from inside a datatemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245936/binding-to-viewmodel-from-inside-a-datatemplate)

Answer (score 4):

You may try the below.

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourViewModel}}, Path=DataContext.ImageClick}" />
```

I think it would help you..

Comment: The answer is quite right except type:   x:Type YourViewModel shall be changed into x:Type YourView