# WPF - ToolTip with multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, multibinding

I want to make a tooltip with multibinding inside a text block, but whatever I try it doesn't work.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, StringFormat='Description : {0}{}'}">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Description : {0}{1}{}">
                    <Binding Path="FirstDescription" />
                    <Binding Path="SecondDescription" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

But when I try it, what I see on the tooltip is : System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.

when i try it without tooltipservice, and only tooltip, like this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, StringFormat='Description : {0}{}'}">
    <ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Description : {0}{1}{}">
                    <Binding Path="FirstDescription" />
                    <Binding Path="SecondDescription" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

The screen just get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

I dont't know wich VS version you are using but:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, StringFormat="Description : {0}{}"}">
```

does not even compile for me.

Just remove the " and the empty brackets like that:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, StringFormat=Description : {0}">
```

You could also write it like this if you want the ":

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Description" StringFormat="Description : {0}" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Description : {0}{1}">
                            <Binding Path="FirstDescription" />
                            <Binding Path="SecondDescription" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Please also remove the empty bracket, just to be sure. Then as I said,  you may have a problem in how you fill your binding, it should work.
It it displays "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" it could mean that you code something like Description = new TextBlock() in your code behind?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code and that worked perfectly:

```
<TextBlock Margin="20" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Text="{Binding Name1}">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="MultiBinded Tooltip : {0}{1}">
                        <Binding Path="Name1"/>
                        <Binding Path="Name2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but all I can see in the tool tip is : System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock

Comment: @Pachu Can you show me the code ? I think you need to implement the override tostring() method in your class.

Comment: @Pachu Have you got the way to multi bind your tool tip?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete empty brackets. Next code work as expected:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, StringFormat='Description : {0}'}">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Description : {0}{1}">
                            <Binding Path="FirstDescription" />
                            <Binding Path="SecondDescription" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

If the StringFormat starts with a left brace { the XAML parser require you to escape it using a pair of braces {}. Otherwise the parser gets confused because braces also are used in the syntax of markup extensions.

Details are found in the XAML documentation for [{} Escape Sequence / Markup Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx).

Also, you can't use double quotes with inline binding but single quotes is available.

Comment: @Pachu ok I answered you about brackets and add whole workong code. Did you still have any problems after using it?

Comment: I do, I see the following text in the tool tip : "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" instead of the text I want.

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your problem. I deleted empty brackets and now code works fine. What version of .net framework do you use? Is it your example is a part of Style/Template or not?

Comment: .net 4.5, and yes it is a part of a data template

Comment: My guess is that "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" is what is actually binded in your tooltip.
What is your code behind to fill Description, FirstDescription and SecondDescription?

Comment: Also you can't bind directly to your viewmodel inside datatemplate. See more [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245936/binding-to-viewmodel-from-inside-a-datatemplate)