# GestureRecognizers does not work inside a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView as follows

```
<ListView
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="0"
        x:Name="ItemsListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems}"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HasUnevenRows="false"
        RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
        ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
        IsVisible="{Binding ShowListView}"
        RowHeight="55">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid
                        Margin="15,0,0,0"
                        Padding="0"
                        RowSpacing="0"
                        ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition
                                Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="7*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HeightRequest="35"
                            WidthRequest="35"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            Source="{Binding Icon}">
                        </Image>
                        <StackLayout
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Spacing="0"
                            CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true"
                            Margin="15,0,0,0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                Text="{Binding Description}"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Image
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            HeightRequest="20"
                            WidthRequest="20"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                        <Image
                            BackgroundColor="Lime"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            InputTransparent="false"
                            Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            HeightRequest="20"
                            WidthRequest="20"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            Source="ic_two">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Command="{Binding OnFavouriteCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

and in my ViewModel I have

```
public ICommand OnFavouriteCommand { get; set; }

public MyViewModel()
{           
  OnFavouriteCommand = new Command<Object>(OnFavourite);
}

void OnFavourite(Object ob)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ob);
}
```

I don't get a `Break Point` hit on `OnFavourite`. I can't figure out what am I missing here? The idea was to get a gesture recognizers attached to each image and pass down the item bound to that row only.

I've just noticed, if I bring

```
<Image
            BackgroundColor="Lime"
            Grid.Row="1"
            InputTransparent="false"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            HeightRequest="20"
            WidthRequest="20"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            Source="ic_favourites">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding OnFavouriteCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                </TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
```

Out side of the `ListView` the break point does get hit!. Left me scratching my head... :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work gesture in listview use like this

```
<Image
    BackgroundColor="Lime"
    Grid.Row="1"
    InputTransparent="false"
    Margin="0,0,10,0"
    HeightRequest="20"
    WidthRequest="20"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    Source="ic_favourites">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding Binding Path=BindingContext.OnFavouriteCommand,Source={x:Reference root}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
        </TapGestureRecognizer>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Here root will be page name like set X:Name of your page be root like  x:Name="root"

Comment: Thanks Adit, extended the model and added in a Command property.

Answer (score 7):

While what Adit wrote is true, let me give you some background. Within the `DataTemplate`, the `BindingContext` of the cells (and hence the children of them) are not set to the `BindingContext` of the parent (i.e. the `ListView`), but for each element from your `ListView.ItemSource` a cell is created and its `BindingContext` is set to that element. Otherwise you would not be able to bind the properties of the `ViewCell`s children to your fields like `Icon`, `Name`, `Description`, etc.

In WPF there is the possibility to bind to the parents `DataContext` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245936/binding-to-viewmodel-from-inside-a-datatemplate)), but AFAIK this is not possible in Xamarin.Forms (see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/63828/#Comment_63828)). Therefor you'll have to reference the parent explicitly, i.e. assign a name via `x:Name="Page"` (or whatever name you'd like to give it) and then reference it via the `Source` property in your binding

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnFavouriteCommand,Source={x:Reference Page}}"
```

Since you set the binding source not the the `BindingContext` of `Page`, but to `Page`, you'll have to add the `BindingContex` to the path. Furthermore, in order to pass the element that is represented by the current cell, to the command, you'll have to set

```
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
```

which binds `CommandParameter` to the element that is referenced by the cell (which you already did).

Comment: Hey Paul. Thanks for the background. I ended up extending the model and added a command property.