# How To Bind Data Command to a button residing in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind command from Business object to View in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596094/bind-command-from-business-object-to-view-in-mvvm)

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="40" Width="*" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="btnedit" Width="25" Height="25" Command="{Binding BanquetSearchCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
                                    <!--<Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BanquetValuConverter}">
                                            <Binding StringFormat="hi"></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>-->
                                    <Image  Width="25" Height="15" Source="/TBC;component/images/Edit_N1.png" ></Image>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="40" Width="*" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="btnDelete" Width="25" Height="25">
                                    <Image  Width="25" Height="15" Source="/TBC;component/images/Delete_N1.png"></Image>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="3" >
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="300 0 0 0" Height="100">
            <Button Content="Add" Foreground="White" Height="23" Margin="38 38 0 38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding BanquetSearchCommand}" >
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BanquetValuConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="btnAdd" Path="Content"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="btnRefresh" Path="Content"/>  

                    </MultiBinding>    
                </Button.CommandParameter>
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TBC;component/images/Add.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="None" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="    Refresh" Foreground="White" Height="23" Margin="20 38 0 38" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="btnRefresh" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TBC;component/images/Refresh.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="None" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Exit" Foreground="White" Height="23" Margin="20 38 0 38" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="btnExit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TBC;component/images/Exit.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="None" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Above is the xaml that I have i want the data grid text column data on clicking of button command of edit and delete.And below is the View Model

```
public ICommand BanquetSearchCommand { get; set; }
 public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //var param = (Tuple<string, string>)parameter;

            List<string> lststring = parameter as List<string>;
            string operation = string.Empty;
            string datarowindex = string.Empty;
            operation = Convert.ToString(lststring[0]).Trim();
            datarowindex = Convert.ToString(lststring[1]).Trim();

            switch (operation)
            {
                case "Add":
                    BlanquetMaster _bnkmaster = new BlanquetMaster();
                    _bnkmaster.ShowDialog();
                    break;
                case "Refresh":
                    break;
                case "Close":
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Please guide me as the edit button not executing the Execute(). I am new new WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelatieSource in binding to specify the Command Binding of button.

```
<Button Command ="{Binding DataContext.BanquetSearchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply .I have change the command as below and set the debugger at Execute() in view model but it is not working as execution not stopped at debug point.
<Button Name="btnedit" Width="25" Height="25" Command="{Binding Datacontext.BanquetSearchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">

Comment: Please check your output window while debugging and see is there any error/exception.

Comment: The thread '<No Name>' (0xfa8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xcf8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: there is nothing happen at all ...The control just lost .. is that the correct way of doing that.Means there are other button present out side the grid .bind with same Icommand property they are working fine.